# How to (properly) install AMDGPU-PRO with Southern Islands GPU?

Tags: drivers, amdgpu, opencl, amdgpu-pro

Problem: I need to install drivers that have OpenCL support (for Tensorflow, PlaidML, etc) on my system that uses 4 Tahiti GPUs (that belong to GCN 1/Southern Islands series), and after a bit of research, I've found that my options are:

- fglrx, but that effectively locks me on Ubuntu 14.04 since 16.04+ has completely removed support of that driver. It works but 14.04 is not desirable.
- AMDGPU + AMDGPU-PRO, which supposedly added support for GCN 1 (a.k.a Southern Islands) recently (see [AMDGPU-PRO 16.50 Rolls Out With Southern Islands Support, FreeSync](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amdgpu-1650-relive&num=1)), but so far I haven't been able to make it work.

---

What I tried:

- On Ubuntu 16.04, installed HWE kernels, appended `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` with `radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1`, installed amdgpu-17.50 with `--opencl=legacy --headless` options. End result was KDE freezing, and black screen after reboot, both of which are easily fixed by running `amdpgu-pro-uninstall`, but it has an unfortunate effect of removing drivers.
- On Ubuntu 18.04, did the same stuff with `/etc/default/grub`, installed amdgpu-pro-19.50 with `--opencl=legacy, --headless, --no-dkms` options. End result was the same black screen, which again was fixed by uninstalling drivers.

---

It's also worth mentioning that in both cases the system was running AMDGPU (without -PRO), and also what really confuses me is that if I type `clinfo` *right after* I install AMDGPU-PRO, it seems to work just fine, but after a minute or two KDE freezes and upon reboot don't even starts, thus forcing me to uninstall *-PRO. Do I miss something obvious here?

---

NB: I also found this: [The Experimental GCN 1.0 GPU Support Might Be Dropped From AMDGPU Linux Driver](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMDGPU-Might-Drop-GCN-1.0) (31 December 2019), which states that AMD would be completely dropping CGN 1 support from *-PRO, but contrary to this I still see people installing *-PRO on systems with CGN 1 here and there on the Internet (Arch, in particular), but they don't have anything specific to say regarding installation of the driver.

Comment: Haven't tried it but Mesa should have some kind of OpenCL support.

Comment: AMD GPU's is a bad choice. They won't support linux. Better don't use them